# Container icons changes for all on selection one

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new to flutter this is my problem,
When I select an icon, I am selecting all the other item in the container

I am not able to change the color of container to green when selected 
not only on icon but also on container function onpressed

```
class _AddEmpToProjectState extends State<AddEmpToProject> {
  bool _isSelected = false;
  Container addEmpListTile() {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0), color: Colors.white),
        child: Container(
          child: ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/tom.jpg'),
              ),
              title: Text('Sam'),
              subtitle: Text('Site Manager'),
              trailing: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    _isSelected = !_isSelected;
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  child: _isSelected
                      ? Icon(
                          Icons.done,
                          color: Colors.green,
                          size: 35.0,
                        )
                      : Icon(
                          Icons.add,
                          color: Colors.deepPurple,
                          size: 35.0,
                        ))),
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add Employees'),
        elevation: 0.0,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.done,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
      ),

      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return addEmpListTile();
        },
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

when container is tapped change color to green and should move to top
if deselected must return back to the array widget index
this is what i am expected to do

Answer (score 0):

Need to track in some way which item is selected (some sort of identifier), not only the fact that an item is selected (boolean).

One solution can be to use `index` as tracking number

```
class _AddEmpToProjectState extends State<AddEmpToProject> {
  -bool _isSelected = false;
  +Set<int> _selected = Set();

...
class _AddEmpToProjectState extends State<AddEmpToProject> {
 Set<int> _selected = Set();

 Container addEmpListTile(int index) {

    ...
    onTap: () {
     setState(() {
       if(_selected.contains(index)) {
        _selected.remove(index);
       } else {
         _selected.remove(index);
       };
     }
    },
    child: _selected.contains(index)
       ? Icon(Icons.done)
       : Icon(Icons.add)
  }

...

  build() {
    ...
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return addEmpListTile(index);  // <-- add index here
    ...
  }
```

Comment: when i select second item ,First item reverts back to the add icon

Comment: sorry not quite sure what you mean

Comment: Oh right, ok I think I know what you mean. You can then track selected icons using a Set

Comment: can u please specify how to do it, like if container is selected it must be colored and once again if the same container is tapped it must return to the previous state as like check box

Comment: that would be `if(_selected.exists(index)) { _selected.remove(index); } else { _selected.add(index); }`

Comment: cannot use .exists

Comment: sorry, it's `contains()`